# Get current time in Date Format

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I need current time to compare with my server time. I got the correct time in string format with this code.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm"
 let datestring = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

But when i again converted string into date format then it showing wrong result.

> String from Date

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm"
let datestring = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Result: 15:30

> Date from String

```
let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "H:mm"
 dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
 dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
 let dateFromString: Date? = dateFormatter1.date(from: datestring)
```

Result: 2000-01-01 10:00:00 +0000

Comment: Since you are printing the `Date` in `GMT+0`, I would guess that the result is actually correct and you are in `GMT+5:30` timezone (e.g. India). The result is correct but you are checking it wrong.

Comment: But i need to get time in this "HH;mm" format.

Comment: If you need `"HH:mm"` then you need a formatter with that `dateFormat` set to that format and convert the date to a string. I don't see anything like that in your code.

Comment: You can see the format in my code "H:mm". i you seems i am doing wrong then please share a code.

Comment: Your code is correct and there is nothing wrong with the result. It's unclear what is your problem.

Comment: Unrelated: You are setting the time zone for `dateFormatter` and not `dateFormatter1`

Answer (score 0):

`dateFromString` is correct. Bear in mind that dates are **always** printed using UTC, and not your timezone. So 10am UTC is actually 3:30pm in your time zone. You are only providing the time `15:30` for `dateFormatter1`. The other date components (year, month, day, seconds) are the default for a `DateFormatter` instance.